# Row separators not showing when section separators hidden

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

When using a combination of `listRowSeparator` and `listSectionSeparator` being `hidden`, list row separators don't show up when appending items to the end of the list.

Here is a simple sample that reproduces the problem:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Item] = []
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                items.append(Item(id: items.count, text: "\(items.count)"))
            } label: {
                Text("Append")
            }
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text(item.text)
                            .listRowSeparator(.visible)
                            .listRowSeparatorTint(Color.red)
                    }
                }
                // Comment out this for row separators to work
                .listSectionSeparator(.hidden, edges: .all)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}
```

This is happening on iOS 15, only when using plain list style, and only when appending to the end of the list.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a SwiftUI bug, the below combination can be considered as workaround

```
Section {
    ForEach(items) { item in
        Text(item.text)
            .listRowSeparatorTint(Color.red)
                     .listRowSeparator(.visible, edges: .bottom)
    }
}
.listSectionSeparator(.hidden, edges: .top)
```

, which gives

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you! While this doesn't completely work around the issue (it still shows the bottom separator) I think it is a good enough solution.